# Whats a url that starts with htlfp & whys it giving me an IE script error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, loadrunner

I've recorded using loadrunner, and Now I get .Net Framework & script errors when I reload the script I recorded (web/http) in loadrunner

I'm getting IE script error (invalid character)
with a line number and character position & a URL that starts htlfp:\WebViewer1*c:\script\scriptname\data\t13.html*http*address*webclient

c:...\t13.html doesn't contain an invalid character - but it does contain lots of entries that start GrahamTechnology.ui.FormParagraph=function(a)....

I guess this means its a reference to a "server command", which I cannot run because I'm no longer connected to the server from whence it was recorded?

Does anyone know what htlfp stands for, is it generic or specific to GrahamTechnology?

How do I make it go away, I thought I could stop it by disabling display Thumbnails in the scripting options - but that does not work ?

Comment: The only information I can see with my Google-foo that sounds relevant is that a product called Quicktest Professional has a file that is sometimes linked to the protocol.

Comment: Do you get errors from VuGen or in the replay log?

Comment: Vugen, haven't tried replay yet - still correlating\parameterizing

Comment: If you have a crash in VuGen could you please send the script to LoadRunner feedback (in VuGen, Help -> LoadRunner feedback). Please mention the exact version you are using with all the patches and how to reproduce the crash.

Comment: Wilco Buzzy, I'm using 11:52, but Im going to download the trial version of Loadrunner 12:00. To see if that helps my current problems :- Recording IE 10 & Chrome support. If I still get the error I'll post via vugen, If its fixed I'll report back here

Comment: Klors...incorrect.    VUGEN and QTP are mutually exclusive in their use.  In this case QTP operates at the end user interface top of the OSI application layer and the Script being recorded operates at the HTTP application layer protocol, which is near the bottom of the OSI application layer and the top of the presentation layer.

Comment: Where I have observed this issue in the past, involving an htlpf reference was in the improper handling of a request by the run time browser.   Turning off the browser and allowing the logs to be reference ended the issue.  Regarding IE 10, look very carefully at your system requirements for your version of LoadRunner.  It is very easy to get caught in a situation where your browser is newer than your test tools so the behavior becomes unpredictable because of the combo never having been tested prior to release.   Go for 12.01